# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'product'

Tags: django

I am absolute new to django and I have followed the example of Django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/
but getting a problem in main project's urls.py file which is Module not found error pls help. Heres my main projects urls.py:

```
`from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path


urlpatterns = [
path('polls/', include('product.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Most likely you missed an import ... but without code … hard to help. Please add your urls.py at least and some traceback.

Comment: Have you added the **product** app in `settings.py`

Comment: is it necessary to add? I don't see this at any tutorials.